# Remove pagination from axlsx result set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack, axlsx

I am using AXLSX to generate xlsx files from a table displayed on a website when a user performs a search using Ransack. My problem is that the results are paginated on the website however I want the spreadsheet to display the full set of results rather than 15 records as is currently the case.

Controller

```
def index
  @search      = Campaign.search(params[:q])
  @campaigns = @search.result.page(params[:page]||1)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xlsx{ render xlsx: 'Campaigns' }
  end
end
```

Link

```
= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></i>'.html_safe, admin_campaigns_path(format: :xlsx), title: "Download Campaign XLS", rel: 'tooltip'
```

Campaigns.xlsx.axlsx

```
require 'axlsx'
xlsx_package = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Campaigns") do |sheet|
  style1 = sheet.styles.add_style(:bg_color => "EF0920", :fg_color => "FFFFFF", :b => "true")
  sheet.add_row ["Header", "Header", "Header", "Header","Header","Header","Header","Header","Header","Header","Header","Header"], :style => style1
  @campaigns.each do |campaign|
    sheet.add_row [campaign.data,campaign.data,campaign.data,campaign.data,campaign.data,ccampaign.data,campaign.data,campaign.data,campaign.data,campaign.data,campaign.data]
  end
end
```

I was thinking of either changing the call to campaigns to something else and removing the pagination but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out:

```
def index
  @search      = Campaign.search(params[:q])
  @campaigns = @search.result
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html{@campaigns = @search.result.page(params[:page]||1)}
    format.xlsx{ render xlsx: 'Campaigns' }
  end
end
```